# C# Live charts set line series to an array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, livecharts

So in LiveCharts to make a "graph line thingy" you do this:

```
SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
{
    new LineSeries
    {
        Values = new ChartValues<double> { 3, 5, 7, 4 }
    },
    new ColumnSeries                
    {
        Values = new ChartValues<decimal> { 5, 6, 2, 7 }
    }
};
```

But if I have an array of int-s vals[] how would I set the LineSeries to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ChartValues<T>` has a constructor that takes `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can construct `LineSeries` like this:

```
int[] vals = ...
LineSeries ls = new LineSeries { Values = new ChartValues<int>(vals) };
```

Comment: OK  this is off topic but how do I feed it live data because my method makes it completely redraw the graph each time a new value is added.

Comment: @MaticBabnik I have no idea - I do not work with live charts. Ask a separate question, and provide the relevant code for how you add a new value.

Comment: OK will do. PS I just switched from VB to C#